# Is it possible to connect gps reciever (teltonika fm1110) to a home server?

Tags: c#, sockets, gps, gprs, umts

My friend has got a Gps receiver installed in his car. The Gps receiver emits signal using GPRS-UMTS network.

I have created a server socket (C#) and listening for connections but am not getting any of them which should be sent from the receiver itself.

The receiver does not have an interface it just sends data and because of that I can not program a client socket on it.

How should I solve such problem? Do I have to have specialised mobile servers to catch such data or am I able to this with my Home server (actually a normal computer which acts as a server).

Comment: Check if the port you're using is open from both your computer and your router.

Comment: The GPS receiver presumably is sending the data to some IP address or host name - how is this configured on the receiver?

Comment: I implemented a  TCP listener which is working on a specific port. I have found out a lot of things. But if I can ask How would I or do I have to create a new protocol for receiving the data from the gps device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you communicate with teltonika fm1100 first you confgure your router to redirect traffic via a specific port number wich you use when configuring your gps

that you have to configure the gps tyo communicate to your public IP server
than  you need a parser to read data received from gps. and first the device send it's IMEI you have to respond to this message with "1" if IMEI is correct "0" if it's not

if you need a c# parser I just wrote one this may help you begin:
https://github.com/temala/Teltonika-FM1100

Comment: Tnx!! Just one more question when you were writing the parser did you use the Teltonika user manual?

Comment: Yes I did and I got some help from the traccar protocol list to translate java to c# and the protocol manual to verify if it's correct https://www.traccar.org/protocols/